# Discord event handler error and i dont know why

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to recode my discord bot now i want to use an event handler.

**event_handler.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
    const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for (const file of eventFiles) {
        const event = require(`../events/${file}`);
        if (event.once) {
            client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
        } else {
            client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
        }
    }
}
```

**ready.js** *(First event)*

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    once: true,
    execute(){
        console.log('[DarkBOT] Bot ist Online');
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
/home/Darkbot/handlers/event_handler.js:9
            client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
                                                       ^

TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is a undefined and not a function
```

I searched online but i dont know if i miss something or whats wrong..
I would be happy if you can help me fix and understand what i'm doing wrong.

EDIT:

[dir tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STuRd.jpg)

[handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTLSI.jpg)

Comment: where do you even call the `Function.prototype.apply`? execute is not the same as apply...

Comment: Yea i know thats why i wonder i never used it.. 
But its weird now i deleted all files and rewrite it and now it seems to work ?
I dont know why..

But big thanks for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `event` is `undefined`.

I tested it myself,and made some changes to your original Code:

```js
//changed module.exports to exports.run
//this allows the code to propperly run

exports.run= (client, Discord) => {
//everything below, I left just as you have it, there did not seem to be any error

const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync("./events").filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"))

    for (const file of eventFiles) {
        const event = require(`../events/${file}`)
        if (event.once) {
            client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client))
        } else {
            client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client))
        }
    }
}
```

Also I added this to my index.js:

```js
const eventHandler = require("./handlers/event_handler.js")
eventHandler.run(client, Discord)
```

This is the folder structure I used:

[image]

Comment: Sadly no..

If i try this error appears:

node:internal/fs/utils:343
    throw err;
    ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '../../events/'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1381:3)

Comment: I have it exactly like you now but still the execute error you can see in my question :/

Comment: can you please attach an exact image of your tree to your question?

Comment: Okay. i uploaded pics from the free

Comment: If i copy the event handler in index.js or in my case darkbot.js it works fine.. only if i do it in another file is that a problem..